# Problemas de memoria ao carregar muitas imagens em listView

Tags: java, android

Fiz uma aplicação onde é possível tirar uma foto e salvar o seu caminho no banco de dados para depois mostrar em um listView junto com outras informações. Tudo corre bem quando há poucas imagens ou imagens pequenas a serem exibidas, porém ao chegar a uma certa quantidade de imagens, a aplicação fica muito lenta chegando as vezes até a parar. 
Esse é o erro que ocorre:

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main 
>   java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 20155404 byte allocation with 16777120 free and 16MB until OOM.

classe para capturar ou selecionar a imagem do cartão sd

```
 public class InicialMy extends Activity {
 private static final int SELECT_PICTURE = 1;
 private static final int CAPTURAR_IMAGEM = 2;
 private static final int REQUEST_IMAGE_PICK = 3;
 private Uri uri;
 private Button irParaLista;

 private String caminho;
 private TextView lugar;
 private String imagePath;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_inicial_my);
        Button save = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);



        File imgFile = new File("/storage/emulated/0/Download/20150617-0013.jpeg");

        if(imgFile.exists()){
            Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgFile.getAbsolutePath());
            ImageView miImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageCapa);
            miImage.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);
        }

        save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Controller dao = new Controller(getBaseContext());

                irParaLista = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonLista);

                EditText nome = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextTitulo);
                EditText dono = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextAutor);
                ImageView foto = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageCapa);

                String result;

                result = dao.insereDado(nome.getText().toString(),dono.getText().toString(),caminho);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });

        Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonImage);
        btn.setOnClickListener(mOnClickListener);
    }

    //começo do button
    private View.OnClickListener mOnClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setType("image/*");
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Selecione a capa do livro"), REQUEST_IMAGE_PICK);
        }
    };
    //fim do button
    public void lista(View view){
        if(view.getId() == R.id.buttonLista){
            startActivity(new Intent(this, ListaCarros.class));
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent){
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);

        switch (requestCode){
        case REQUEST_IMAGE_PICK:
            if(RESULT_OK == resultCode){
                Uri imageUri = intent.getData();

                ImageView imagemCapa = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageCapa);
                imagemCapa.setImageURI(imageUri);
                imagePath = getImagePath(imageUri);
                Toast.makeText(this, imagePath, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                caminho = imagePath;

            }
        break;
        case CAPTURAR_IMAGEM:
             if(requestCode == CAPTURAR_IMAGEM){
                mostrarMensagem("Imagem capturada");
                adicionarNaGaleria();
            }

        }
    }


    public String getImagePath(Uri contentUri){
        String [] campos = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(contentUri, campos, null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        String path = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA));
        cursor.close();
        return path;
    }


    private void adicionarNaGaleria(){
        Intent intent = new Intent(
                    Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE
                );
        intent.setData(uri);
        this.sendBroadcast(intent);
    }

    private void mostrarMensagem(String msg){
        Toast.makeText(this, msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    public void capturarImagem(View view){
        File diretorio = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);

        String nomeImagem = diretorio.getPath()+"/"+System.currentTimeMillis()+".jpg";

        uri = Uri.fromFile(new File(nomeImagem));

        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, uri);

        startActivityForResult(intent, CAPTURAR_IMAGEM);
    }
    public void visualizarImagem(View view){
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.setDataAndType(uri, "image/jpeg");
        startActivity(intent);
    }

 }
```

classe para mostrar a lista:

```
public class ListaCarros extends ActionBarActivity {
private CarrosAdapter adaptador;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_lista_carros);
    List<Carro> lista;
    ListView controle;
    Controller dao = new Controller(getBaseContext());
    Cursor cursor = dao.carregaDados();
    lista = cursor2List(cursor);
    adaptador = new CarrosAdapter(getApplication(),R.layout.layout_carros, lista);
    controle = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);
    controle.setAdapter(adaptador);
}

protected List<Carro> cursor2List(Cursor cursor){
    List<Carro> carros = new ArrayList<Carro>();
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    do{
        Carro carro = new Carro();

        carro.setNome(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.NOME)));
        carro.setDono(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.DONO)));
        carro.setFoto(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.FOTO)));

        carros.add(carro);
    }while(cursor.moveToNext());
    return carros;
}
}
```

classe para controlar a inserção de dados:

```
public class Controller {

 private SQLiteDatabase db;
    private DBHelper banco;

    public Controller(Context context){
        banco = new DBHelper(context);
    }

    public String insereDado(String nome, String dono,  String caminho){
        ContentValues valores;
        long resultado;
        db = banco.getWritableDatabase();

        valores = new ContentValues();
        valores.put(banco.NOME,nome);
        valores.put(banco.DONO,dono);
        valores.put(banco.FOTO,caminho);
        resultado = db.insert(banco.TABELA,null,valores);
        db.close();

        if(resultado==-1){
            return "ERRO";
        }else{
            return "Inserido com Sucesso";
        }
    }
    public Cursor carregaDados(){
        Cursor cursor;
        String[] campos =  {banco.ID,banco.NOME,banco.DONO,banco.FOTO};
        db = banco.getReadableDatabase();
        cursor = db.query(banco.TABELA, campos, null, null, null, null, null, null);

        if(cursor!=null){
            cursor.moveToFirst();
        }
        db.close();
        return cursor;
    }
 }
```

carros adapter:

```
public class CarrosAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Carro>{
Context contexto;
int id;
List<Carro> lista;
public CarrosAdapter(Context contexto, int id, List<Carro> lista){
    super(contexto,id,lista);
    this.contexto = contexto;
    this.lista = lista;
    this.id = id;

}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
    View view = convertView;
    Carro carro;
    ImageView foto;
    TextView nome;
    TextView dono;
    Bitmap raw;
    TextView caminho;

    if(view == null){
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(contexto);
        view = inflater.inflate(id, parent, false);
    }

    nome = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textView);
    dono = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textView3);
    foto = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    caminho = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textViewCaminho);

    carro = lista.get(position);

    nome.setText(carro.getNome());
    dono.setText(carro.getDono());

    File imgFile = new File(carro.getFoto());
    Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgFile.getAbsolutePath()); 

    foto.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);



    caminho.setText(carro.getFoto());

    return view;
}
}
```

Alguém pode me ajudar a resolver esse problema de memória?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isso acontece porque quando se trabalha com imagens no Android uma grande **quantidade de memoria é alocada** e você teria que tratar isso ao invés de passar direto para **setImageBitmap(myBitmap);**
Sugiro que você use bibliotecas de auxilio como Glide,Picasso e etc pesquisando no Google você acha bastante. Tente isso.
No seu Gradle adicione:

```
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
```

Depois no seu Adapter mude

```
  ...nome = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textView);
dono = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textView3);
foto = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
caminho = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textViewCaminho);

carro = lista.get(position);

nome.setText(carro.getNome());
dono.setText(carro.getDono());
```

Picasso.with(context).load(new File(carro.getFoto())).into(foto);

```
caminho.setText(carro.getFoto());...
```

Você pode fazer varias coisas com essas libs:  crop, cash etc... segue o doc da lib [Picasso Doc](http://square.github.io/picasso/)

Comment: E bom que você use o crop também isso otimiza bastante

Comment: obrigado pela ajuda, realmente foi de grande ajuda, já estou procurando (como um louco) por essas bibliotecas! muito obrigado

Answer (score 0):

Não lhe vou dar uma solução completa porque tal implicaria escrever um tutorial.
Para resolver o problema do *OutOfMemoryError* substitua a linha

```
Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgFile.getAbsolutePath());
```

por

```
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();

//Comece com 2 mas experimente valores maiores de acordo com a sua necessidade, 
//quanto maior o valor menor a memória necessária mas mais pequena será a imagem.
options.inSampleSize = 2;//O valor deverá ser uma potência de 2: 2, 4, 8, 16, etc.

Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgFile.getAbsolutePath(), options);
```

O *Bitmap* gerado será uma versão reduzida do original cujo tamanho é função do valor atribuído a *inSampleSize*.

Ao resolver o erro *OutOfMemoryError* outros problemas irão surgir por isso aconselho que leia a documentação [aqui](http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html) e [aqui](http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/training/displaying-bitmaps/process-bitmap.html)

Poder-lhe-ia indicar bibliotecas prontas que solucionam para si estes problemas mas julgo que é mais interessante se você primeiro aprendesse como as coisas funcionam.

Comment: obrigado pelo ajuda, realmente melhorou a velocidade e já estou lendo a documentação para evitar outros erros. muito obrigado!